# can somone explain this syntax for me [Animation<double> animation = new Tween<double>();]

Tags: flutter, dart

This sound nooby but i had to ask...
`Animation<double> animation = new Tween<double>();`
what am not understanding here is, why are we creating a Tween instance but assigning it to a reference variable,animation, of type Animation?

Comment: That should not be legal; `Tween` is not assignable to an `Animation`.  Are you sure that the code isn't `animation = Tween<...>(...).animate(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

From my understaing, `Animation` is kind of a holder for a specific animation (like `Tween`).

You need to call the `.animate()` method in Tween to return an Animation object.

Like:  `Tween<double>().animate( ... )`

---

So with this code, you are creating a `Tween` effect, and assigning it to tha animation holder.

The Animation have a **status**. With this you can check the current status of this animation.

The Animation also "let other objects listen for changes".

---

Check this documentation:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Animation-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Tween-class.html

Comment: thanks, actually i wasn't aware of the method ,'animate(animController)'